# Google reCAPTCHA response

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I've set up Google's invisible reCAPTCHA on both my client and server and I'm able to verify the responses from Google on the server.

The docs state [that](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#site-verify-response):

```
{
  "success": true|false,      // whether this request was a valid reCAPTCHA token for your site
  "score": number             // the score for this request (0.0 - 1.0)
  "action": string            // the action name for this request (important to verify)
  "challenge_ts": timestamp,  // timestamp of the challenge load (ISO format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ)
  "hostname": string,         // the hostname of the site where the reCAPTCHA was solved
  "error-codes": [...]        // optional
}
```

What I'm particularly interested in is the "success" field. What is a "valid reCAPTCHA token"? are requests from bots filling the form considered valid with low score?

Comment: Isnt that google's secret not tell anyone how it works?

Comment: To my understanding it's the `score` field that they keep secret how they populate it.